# how to solve this error 1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: php, ssl, curl

in our application we integrate with another system we were given HTTPs URL and every member of the team worked on their machine with no problem and without any additional configuration for ssl or adding any certificate but for me I tried every thing adding ssl and a punch of certificates and it didn't work and tried to turn off firewall it didn't work.

and I tried to make this curl but it didn't work

```
<?php
$url = "https url";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array(
   "Content-Type: application/json",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$data = '{"to":"eyJpdiI6InFvVDUvNUp2aWdmcjBGaytTaS84alE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiK29aVlBhNk5TRVgzb2Z3Qm45cHB5L1hSZEYwMWxTajhMSDJDWHlIOXpRMD0iLCJtYWMiOiIwYmExYzczMjM1NjUxZjBiNzdmMWE2YjhlODQxZjMzODQ5NWYyYThhMTQ5YWIwODhkOTA0ZTczNzQxYjc2NDhiIiwidGFnIjoiIn0=","from":"+123456789","isTemplate":"1","message":"hello","agent":"test"}';
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
$error_msg = curl_error($curl);
echo($error_msg);
?>
```

I expect to get any message like failed to authenticate but instead I got this message: bool(false) with error 1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

when I'm sending post request to the same url in postman application it gives me this message:
Error: write EPROTO 77518472:error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER:../../../../src/third_party/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.cc:242:

but when I use web postman it works so I don't know why it's not working on my local machine!!

Comment: A common cause of this problem is when the server is returning a non-TLS response in the TLS handshake. This happens if one is trying to access a URL which is not properly configured for HTTPS, or if one is trying to access a proxy in the wrong way, or if their is some captive portal or other intercepting proxy which returns a plain HTTP response.  Unfortunately nothing is known about the actual URL nor about any proxy settings or the network setup.